# Mule OAuth Provider Accesstoken expiry time

Tags: oauth, mule

I am using Mule enterprise edition and struggling to find the default expiry time for tokens issued using the Mule OAuth provider. So if my provider configuration is like the below, for how long will the issued access token be valid ? 12 hours/24 hours or something else ?

```
<oauth2-provider:config name="oauth2-provider"
    providerName="E2 Provider" resourceOwnerSecurityProvider-ref="boston-security-provider"
    scopes="READ WRITE" supportedGrantTypes="RESOURCE_OWNER_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS"
    doc:name="OAuth provider module" port="${auth.port}" enableRefreshToken="true">
    <oauth2-provider:clients>           
      <oauth2-provider:client clientId="${web_client_id}"
            secret="${web_client_secret}" type="CONFIDENTIAL" clientName="Web Client"
            description="Mobile Client desc">
            <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
                <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>PASSWORD</oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>
                <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>REFRESH_TOKEN</oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>
            </oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
            <oauth2-provider:scopes>
                <oauth2-provider:scope>READ</oauth2-provider:scope>
                <oauth2-provider:scope>WRITE</oauth2-provider:scope>
            </oauth2-provider:scopes>
        </oauth2-provider:client>
    </oauth2-provider:clients>
</oauth2-provider:config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer it is 86400 seconds which is 24 hours. Link to the documentation is [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+an+OAuth+2.0a+Web+Service+Provider), however the description for Token Ttl Seconds is misleading, It should be seconds instead of milliseconds. I have logged a jira for the same [here](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8570)